# How can I convince students a certain polynomial equation is symmetric?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, education, symmetric-polynomials

How can I convince students that $p(x)=0$ is a symmetric equation if they ask me, where

$p(x)$ is polynomial of degree $n$ with reals coefficients. For example :

$A(x)=2x^4-9x^3+8x^2-9x+2=0 $ is symmetric equation can be solved in $\mathbb{R}$ by taking

$z=x+\frac{1}{x}$ and $x \neq 0$ .

Note : $z$ and $x$ are reals numbers .

I would be interested in any replies or any comments. Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure he means "convince" and not "convict" :)

Comment: How do you define a symmetric polynomial?The definition I know is that a polynomial of several variables is symm. if any permutation of variables gives you the same polynomial.for instance :$P(x,y)=x^2y^2+xy=P(y,x)$. then any polynomial of one variable is automatically symmetric.

Comment: thanks for your editing question, i have problem in my clavier

Comment: I mean symetric polynomial equation if it's can be solved by the variable change cited in the question, mayeb in the notion of Galois

Comment: Well, if it can be solved by your substitution $z$, then it seems you could convince your students by solving it.

Comment: but before taking this variable change , how student see it can be solved with this substitutions

Comment: and why i  take the  variable change cited ? under what basics let me to take it ?

Comment: I don't see how that substitution makes it any easier.  As written, $x = (1/2)(-z \pm \sqrt{z^2-4})$.  Or, if you actually meant $x = z + (1/z)$, now I have a more complicated equation with a bunch of negative exponents.

Comment: But I gather the symmetric part is that the coefficients are symmetric:  $(2,-9,8,-9,2)$?

Comment: Suggest the word palindromic, which is sometimes used in this situation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome

Comment: pleas no , don't put your variable change at the begin of solving , look : $p(x)$=$x²(2(x²+\frac{1}{x²})-9(x+\frac{1}{x})+8))=0$ in this step you can use your sibstitutions , pleas the goal of this sibstitutions is to transform $p(x)$ to quadratic form

Answer (score 1):

They do not say anything about  Berber or French, however: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome#Palindromes_in_Arabic_language

Yes, if you divide a **palindromic** polynomial through by the middle power of the variable, you get your substitution:

$$ 2 x^2 - 9 x + 8 - \frac{9}{x} + \frac{2}{x^2}.  $$ Next use
$$ \left( x + \frac{1}{x}  \right)^2 = x^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{x^2}  $$
and there is no difficulty writing the original problem in terms of 
$$  w = x + \frac{1}{x} $$

Less sure what happens in odd degree; $x^3 - 7 x^2 - 7 x + 1.$ Wait: guaranteed that $x=-1$ is a root. $(x+1)(x^2 - 8x + 1).$ So, if we start with
$$ x^5 -37 x^4 + 23 x^3 + 23 x^2 - 37 x + 1 = (x+1)(x^4 - 38 x^3 + 61 x^2 - 38 x + 1).   $$
LATHER, RINSE, REPEAT.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but my question is not solving the equation p(x)=0, i want just to show and convince my student that there are algebraic methods let me taking the precedent varibales change (symetric coefficients) as example

Comment: @user51189, see this new problem by someone else: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055858/a-problem-about-polynomials-and-galois-theory